# How to correctly (re) interpret encoded text?

Tags: python, encoding, decoding

As a simple use case in Python, I wish to convert some encoded text and set it equal to a variable or dictionary key as would be printed on screen. This issue came about by piping some std out to memory from a command line function where some of the text didn't seem to be properly interpreted in python.

Example:

```
myVar = "N\x08NA\x08AM\x08ME\x08E"
print(myVar)
="NAME"
```

When myVar is input as a dictionary key, I get the following result:

```
myDict = {}
myDict[myVar] = 'foobar'
print(myDict.keys())
=dict_keys(['N\x08NA\x08AM\x08ME\x08E'])
```

How can I make `myDict.keys() = dict_keys(['Name'])?`

Same question for a variable where

```
myVar = "NAME"
```

rather than `'N\x08NA\x08AM\x08ME\x08E'`

I've tried variants of `myVar.encode()` and `str(myVar)` with no success.

Comment: That's not encoded. `\x08` is the same as `\b`, which is a backspace character. When you print a backspace it moves the cursor to the left, so the next character overwrites what was there.

Comment: Where are these coming from? This is rarely used except when formatting output. Some programs will interpret "character backspace character" as a way of printing a character in bold (because that's how you did it on old fashioned printing terminals).

Comment: I don't think there's anything built-in that interprets them in Python.

Comment: `\x08` is the backspace, which is problematic. You could strip non-printable characters, but you'd end up with 'NNAAMMEE', which still isn't 'NAME'. Perpahs a custom function that handles a few known problem characters as you bump into them.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily remove every character that would be erased by a backspace (`\x08` or `\b`) with a regular expression.

```
import re
re.sub('.\x08', '', "N\x08NA\x08AM\x08ME\x08E")
='NAME'
```

Comment: Yes, I appreciate your response. I was hoping to draw from an existing python utility/function to fix some of the text interpretation issues, but ended up using regex to massage the text similar to your suggestion. I used 1) while '\x08' in output; output = re.sub('[^\x08]\x08', '', output) and also output = re.sub('\s\s+', ' ', output).

Comment: @TristanWellman there are no "text interpretation issues".  It's just that the text displayed by your terminal is being erased by the backspace - those characters are still part of the string, even if you ultimately can't see them.  My answer just creates a string that is similar to what you see in the terminal by erasing the character before the backspace.  Isn't my answer simpler than the one you came up with?  I think it's also less prone to error.

Comment: I appreciate the response and clarification on what a human visualizes on screen. Well strictly speaking, your solution did not fully resolve the issue. It does resolve the basic problem example I provided, yes, but does not remove multiple backspaces in sequence for instance, which apparently were generated during the text conversion steps. I included a successful code solution above, which is also very simple code wise. Thanks again.\

Comment: @TristanWellman after looking at your regular expression more closely, I can see that it's very similar to mine and probably technically more correct since it only erases a non-backspace preceding a backspace.  Clever use of the `while` loop to handle multiple backspaces in a row too, it's almost recursive.  I concede that your solution is better and will stop pestering you.