# Reading strings with special characters in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a string with special characters as follows

```
req_str = 'N\x08NA\x08AM\x08ME'
## If I print it I correctly get the word "NAME"
print(req_str)

>>> print(req_str)
NAME
```

Now I want to extract the string `NAME` from the string.
I tried

```
''.join(c for c in 'N\x08NA\x08AM\x08ME' if c.isprintable())
## this produces
'NNAAMME'
```

I understand this has got to do with some special encoding. I am not very familiar with string encodings. My question is how can I extract the word 'NAME` as a string in this situation ?

Comment: It looks the same as this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67203922/how-to-correctly-re-interpret-encoded-text

Comment: Interestingly the word is also exactly the same :) Probably that question also tries to parse man pages of linux :)

Comment: Whether you see `NAME` or not as the output of `print` depends on the file being written to. Your terminal interprets`\x08` as an instruction to move the cursor back one position, displaying the following character "on top" of the previous character. If you want to extract `NAME`, you basically have to simulate how the terminal displays characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the ASCII table, `\x08` is for backspace character. It can also be produced by `\b`:

```py
req_str1 = "N\x08NA\x08AM\x08ME"
req_str2 = "N\bNA\bAM\bME"
print(req_str1)
print(req_str2)
print(req_str1 == req_str2)
```

output:

```
NAME
NAME
True
```

Basically it writes a `N` and then applies backspace then writes another `N`. That's why you see one `N` in the final output. Same thing for `A`, `M` and `E`.

To extract `NAME` you can do what terminal does with it:

(thanks to @DarkKnight)

```py
def extract(s):
    BS = "\x08"
    r = []
    for c in s:
        if c == BS:
            r = r[:-1]
        else:
            r.append(c)
    return ''.join(r)

req_str = 'N\x08NA\x08AM\x08ME'

s = extract(req_str)

print(len(req_str))
print(s)
print(len(s))
```

**Additional Information:** If you wonder what the root of this is: back in the old days printers/typewriters used this technique to type a character twice to make it **Bold**. It's called [overstriking or overtyping](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118709/503892)

Comment: re.sub only works if the characters either side of BS are identical

Comment: @S.B without knowing the origin of the string you can't be **sure** the characters on either side of the BS will be the same.  If you want to simulate an old terminal you should only erase the character before the BS, not the one after.

Comment: Your regular expression will give incorrect results if there's more than one BS in a row, but it's good for the example in the question.  And +1 for explaining how the convention originated.